# Erase space in splitting - R

Tags: r, datetime, time, split

I have a dataframe where I splitted the datetime column by date and time (two columns). However, when I group by time it gives me duplicates in time. So, to analyze it I used table() on time column, and it gave me duplicates also. This is a sample of it:

```
> table(df$time)
 00:00:00 00:00:00   00:15:00 00:15:00   00:30:00 00:30:00
     2211      1047      2211      1047      2211      1047
```

As you may see, when I splitted one of the "unique" values kept a `" "` inside. Is there a easy way to solve this?

PS: The datatype of the time column is character.

**EDIT: Code added**

```
df$datetime <- as.character.Date(df$datetime)
x <- colsplit(df$datetime, ' ', names =  c('Date','Time'))
df <- cbind(df, x)
```

Comment: Can you please include your code? We definitely need to see how you split the columns.

Comment: `trimws` is an easy way to trim whitespace

Comment: @divibisan done !

Comment: `reshape2::colsplit` accepts regular expressions, so you could split on `'\\s+'` which matches 1 or more whitespace characters.

Comment: @divibisan what means '\\s+' ? Could you refer me to a documentation? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: `\\s` means a single whitespace character (space, tab, etc.). The `+` is a quantifier that means that the preceding character must match 1 or more times.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches. One of them is to use appropriate functions to extract Dates and Times from Datetime column:

```
df <- data.frame(datetime = seq(
  from=as.POSIXct("2018-5-15 0:00", tz="UTC"),
  to=as.POSIXct("2018-5-16 24:00", tz="UTC"),
  by="30 min") )

head(df$datetime)
#[1] "2018-05-15 00:00:00 UTC" "2018-05-15 00:30:00 UTC" "2018-05-15 01:00:00 UTC" "2018-05-15 01:30:00 UTC"
#[5] "2018-05-15 02:00:00 UTC" "2018-05-15 02:30:00 UTC"

df$Date <- as.Date(df$datetime)
df$Time <- format(df$datetime,"%H:%M:%S")

    head(df)
#     datetime       Date     Time
# 1 2018-05-15 00:00:00 2018-05-15 00:00:00
# 2 2018-05-15 00:30:00 2018-05-15 00:30:00
# 3 2018-05-15 01:00:00 2018-05-15 01:00:00
# 4 2018-05-15 01:30:00 2018-05-15 01:30:00
# 5 2018-05-15 02:00:00 2018-05-15 02:00:00
# 6 2018-05-15 02:30:00 2018-05-15 02:30:00


table(df$Time)
#00:00:00 00:30:00 01:00:00 01:30:00 02:00:00 02:30:00 03:00:00 03:30:00 04:00:00 04:30:00 05:00:00 05:30:00 
#3        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2 
#06:00:00 06:30:00 07:00:00 07:30:00 08:00:00 08:30:00 09:00:00 09:30:00 10:00:00 10:30:00 11:00:00 11:30:00 
#2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2 
#12:00:00 12:30:00 13:00:00 13:30:00 14:00:00 14:30:00 15:00:00 15:30:00 16:00:00 16:30:00 17:00:00 17:30:00 
#2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2 
#18:00:00 18:30:00 19:00:00 19:30:00 20:00:00 20:30:00 21:00:00 21:30:00 22:00:00 22:30:00 23:00:00 23:30:00 
#2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2        2 




#If the data were given as character strings and contain extra spaces the above approach will still work
df <- data.frame(datetime=c("2018-05-15 00:00:00","2018-05-15   00:30:00",
                            "2018-05-15  01:00:00", "2018-05-15      02:00:00",
                            "2018-05-15 00:00:00","2018-05-15   00:30:00"), 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df$Date <- as.Date(df$datetime)
df$Time <- format(as.POSIXct(df$datetime, tz="UTC"),"%H:%M:%S")
head(df)
#                   datetime       Date     Time
# 1      2018-05-15 00:00:00 2018-05-15 00:00:00
# 2    2018-05-15   00:30:00 2018-05-15 00:30:00
# 3     2018-05-15  01:00:00 2018-05-15 01:00:00
# 4 2018-05-15      02:00:00 2018-05-15 02:00:00
# 5      2018-05-15 00:00:00 2018-05-15 00:00:00
# 6    2018-05-15   00:30:00 2018-05-15 00:30:00

table(df$Time)
#00:00:00 00:30:00 01:00:00 02:00:00 
#       2        2        1        1
```

Answer (score 0):

`reshape2::colsplit` accepts regular expressions, so you could split on '\s+' which matches 1 or more whitespace characters.

You can find out more about regular expressions in R using `?base::regex`. The syntax is generally constant between languages, so you can use pretty much any regex tutorial. Take a look at https://regex101.com/. This site evaluates your regular expressions in real time and shows you exactly what each part is matching. It is extremely helpful!

Keep in mind that in R, as compared to most other languages, you must **double the number of backslashes** `\`. So `\s` (to match 1 whitespace character) must be written as `\\s` in R.